# CanvasJS line chart how to start a line from middle of chart

Tags: javascript, php, canvasjs

I have a chart that starts from 1/6 (dd/mm) and stop to 30/6 and i want to start a line from 15/6 but in linechart label will be overwrited like in image:
[image]

It's start with 18, 19, 15, but if i remove yellow line will start corectly 13/14/15.

Comment: Please include your code in the question and clarify your question :)

Comment: I don't know what you don't understand, if you ar looking that image you will see the problem, First line has value from 13 to 30, and yellow line has from 18 to 19 and will overwrite 13 and 14 from first line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render a line that starts later than the earliest date in your dataset, use *null* as the Y-value for the line datapoints where no value exists.

See the documentation here: https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/empty-null-data-points-chart/